# NodeJS Extended ASCII Support

Tags: node.js, encoding, ascii

I'm trying to read a file that contains extended ascii characters like 'á' or 'è', but NodeJS doesn't seem to recognize them.

I tried reading into:

- Buffer
- String

Tried differente encoding types:

- ascii
- base64
- utf8

as referenced on http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with the way you are using node's fs module. Reading the file as UTF-8 (which is node's default) should read extended ASCII just fine. Please post a code sample and we can help you debug it.

Comment: I just figured out that nodepad++ is able to convert from which ever format to UTF-8. The file was in ANSI, and when I tried to read it in utf-8, it wouldn't recognize the extended ascii characters. I just converted it first, and I was able to read it correctly!

Comment: Sorry for not posting any code, but since I figured it out doesn't seem necessary. Thank you Peter

Comment: You could mark Seth's post as the correct answer, since he actually solves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the binary type to read such files.  For example

```
var fs = require('fs');

// this comment has I'm trying to read a file that contains extended ascii characters like 'á' or 'è',

fs.readFile("foo.js", "binary", function zz2(err, file) {  
    console.log(file);
});
```

When I do save the above into foo.js, then the following is shown on the output:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// this comment has I'm trying to read a file that contains extended ascii characters like '⟡ 漀爀 ✀',

fs.readFile("foo.js", "binary", function zz2(err, file) {  
    console.log(file);
});
```

The wierdness above is because I have run it in an emacs buffer.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I would be able to perform string operations to binary data. I don't know if there's a way to convert it to String, but I already found the answer.

Comment: The 'file' variable in zz2 is an instance of string.

Comment: The `binary` encoding is deprecated, raw `Buffer`s should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

The file I was trying to read was in ANSI encoding. When I tried to read it using the 'fs' module's functions, it couldn't perform the conversion of the extended ASCII characters.

I just figured out that nodepad++ is able to actually convert from some formats to UTF-8, instead of just flagging the file with UTF-8 encoding.

After converting it, I was able to read it just fine and apply all the operations I needed to the content.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but I found it in my personal search for a solution to this particular problem.

I have written a module that provides Extended ASCII decoding and encoding support to/from Node Buffers. [You can see the source code here.](https://github.com/jvilk/bfs-buffer/blob/2d7544c4aaeb683f009efa6dbef9e746270bda49/ts/extended_ascii.ts) It is a part of my implementation of Buffer in the browser for an in-browser filesystem I've created called BrowserFS, but it can be used 100% independently of any of that within NodeJS (or Browserify) as it has no dependencies.

Just add [`bfs-buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfs-buffer) to your dependencies and do the following:

```
var ExtendedASCII = require('bfs-buffer/js/extended_ascii').default;
// Decodes the input buffer as an extended ASCII string.
ExtendedASCII.byte2str(aBufferWithText);
// Encodes the input string as an extended ASCII string.
ExtendedASCII.str2byte("Some text");
```

Alternatively, just adapt the module into your project if you don't want to add an extra dependency to your project. It's MIT Licensed.

I hope this helps anyone in the future who finds this page in their searches like I did. :)